# how to display smallest 3 values in a list with the same index as another list

Tags: python, list

I want to display the three lowest values in the africa list and the year they occured
My current code is as follows:

```
from heapq import nsmallest 
year = [1995,1996,1997,1998,1999,2000]

africa = [1045,928,947,987,1092,1764]

print(nsmallest(3, africa))
```

is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 1):

It is simplest to combine the data first, like this `zip(africa, year)` and then find the results:

```
>>> print(nsmallest(3, zip(africa, year)))
[(928, 1996), (947, 1997), (987, 1998)]
```